# Is there OCR software for HP Laserjet Pro MFP M130A multifunction printer?

Tags: software-recommendation, hp, ocr, laserjet

Is there any OCR software available for HP Laserjet Pro MFP M130A multifunction printer? How can I install it? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have the correct HPLIP installed gscan2pdf from the Ubuntu Software Center has an OCR facility.

[image]